# How to change text after succes in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to change a text after I submit a form. I want when I click at `submit to friend 1` then text change to `Invited to Your friend` but not change `submit to friend 2`. And When I click `submit to friend 2` then change text of `submit to friend 2`.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next().find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });

    function send_to_friend(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"mail.php",
                data:dataString,
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                            $('.panel').slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.flip').html("Invited to Your friend");        
                        }
            });                  
            return false;
    }

</script>
```

My form is here..

```
<style> 
.flip{
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2ea3f2;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.panel{
        margin:5px 0;
        padding:21px;
        display:none;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
.submitfield_style{
    width: 87px;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

<h5 class="flip">Send to a friend 1<h5>
<div class="panel">
   <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submitfield_style" onClick="return send_to_friend()">
    </form>
</div>

    <h5 class="flip">Send to a friend 2<h5>
    <div class="panel">
       <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submitfield_style" onClick="return send_to_friend()">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same class identifier for both the `<h>` elements. It will change the text for both. You need to use the different identifier which you will use in your Ajax code to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same class `flip` for both elements, it will change both.

You could use different classes on those elements, or you could add an attribute to the element that you use in the `<h5>` to specifically distinguish it.

Something like....

`<h5 class="flip" flip-elem="1">Send to a Friend 1</h5>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are applying the action to a specific `class`, it is applied to all the elements that have the `selected class`. You can avoid this by targeting the last element using the `closest() and prev()` functions like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next().find(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
   
      $('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
        $(this).closest('.panel').slideUp("slow");
        $(this).closest('.panel').prev('.flip').html('Invited to Your friend');
        e.preventDefault();
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="flip">Send to a friend 1</h5>
<div class="panel">
   <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submitfield_style" >
    </form>
</div>

    <h5 class="flip">Send to a friend 2</h5>
    <div class="panel">
      
       <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submitfield_style" >
        </form>
    </div>
```

Also you haven't closed the `<h5>` tag
I have written the above onClick handler in jquery, You can try the same with the way you are using. Only thing is that you need to get access to the clicked element's DOM.

Comment: Did you try the solution, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Dear My task is that first click at `send to a friend` then flip-down where you write a message and write an e-mail address and if press submit button the send a mail to friend and then wrote `Invited to Your friend` instead `send to friend`.... (a) page not reload (b) at page do not know how many `send to friend` (c)HTML code do not change means like that